# Sharepoint 2016 Add functionality on check in?

Tags: custom-actions, 2016, check-in

Does anybody know if it is possible to add custom functionality on check in?

For example I wanted to create some functionality where we check content to see if there are any spelling mistakes, dead links in the content once the user has clicked check in.

I did a search myself but I've not been able to find anything. Any help or pointers to reference material would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather you can't edit the check in functionality itself but through the use of event receivers you can trigger custom actions on events such as check in.